# Specify the user to use when trying to connect to a Sharepoint 2010 through LinqToSharepoint

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, credentials

I've a Sharepoint 2010 with which I've to exchange information. I took a look on Caml queries, but it really to messy for me, then I watched the LINQ to sharepoint. This was perfect for what I needed to do!

I generated my code through SPMetal.exe, with an xml config file which makes SPMetal to generate only the code for the list which interest me.

But, once the code is generated, I don't see any place where I can specify credentials. My application has to ask theses and try to connect with them. With caml queries, I was doing this with NetworkCredentials, and assigning them to the context, but I don't see any Credentials properties on the generated datacontext.

So how can I specify an user to use to make these requests?

Some precisions: I would like to do a 32 bit client which connect to a 64 bits server. And I didn't found any other way than get dll from the GAC of the server.

Thank you

Comment: Are you writing an application using the Client Object Model? If so, you can't use LINQ to SharePoint as it's a server side only thing

Comment: Yeah, it's a client application.
So I'm very disappointed, I was thinking that Linq2Sharepoint will really help to deal with this mess of CAML :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is... This isn't possible. Like JamesLove said, LinqToSharepoint hasn't been designed to run in another place than the server. Then it cannot be used to access to the server from a client :(